# El-Cap Mail app intermittent IMAP connection issues

Tags: mail.app, gmail, imap

The issues started occurring after upgrade to 10.11 but not sure if related or not.

I have 2 gmail accounts defined on my Mail app. Most of the time (around 70% or so) all is healthy.

[image]

But every few minutes, the alert signs show up next to both of the accounts. The connection doctor points the blame at IMAP

[image]

This lasts for a while, usually a few minutes. I immediately check my internet connection by pinging various public IPs - all is rock solid. After a while this goes away.

Any idea why this may happen and how I can troubleshoot? I'm tending to not suspect an account setup issue as all works well most of the time. BTW - both of the accounts were set up very basic - just selected Gmail as the account type and added user and password. Did not mock around with anything else more advanced.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is reported so often that it is likely there are multiple causes.  But after many months of putting up with *this exact issue,* here is what worked for me:

**Mail => Preferences => General => Check for new messages**

The default setting is **Automatically**

Change this to **Every 5 minutes**

I imagine anything will work except "Automatically".  My guess is that the Automatic option leaves a connection open to the imap server, and this is what gets screwed up.  I have not tested but it also possible the problem occurs because I click the manual download button while Mac Mail is set to Automatic download.  All I know is that this has been a continuing annoyance for a long time and with this change, it works.

Answer (score 0):

After years of IMAP timeouts and related headaches, this solved it for me: a NVRAM / PRAM reset.

Full credit to MikeInCanberra in this discussion:

https://discussions.apple.com/message/26974748#message26974748

And more info on resetting your Mac's NVRAM / PRAM:

http://www.macworld.com/article/2881177/how-to-reset-your-macs-nvram-pram-and-smc.html

Finally, a consistent, working solution.